# «Can't resolve 'aws-sdk'» while it not a direct dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, newrelic

I have [newrelic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newrelic) among dependencies.
When I try to build application I get

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@newrelic/native-metrics/lib/pre-build.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in …
```

And *aws-sdk* **is** dependency of *newrelic*. I may install aws-sdk as dependency of my application, but it feels wrong.

Comment: have you got a solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue! Did you find a solution?

Comment: Who were you, DenverCoder9? What did you see?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk#in-the-browser-1

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk#in-nodejs-1

Comment: still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
const nock = require('nock');
```

In my case, I simply located the directory where the above code is located in node_modules and commented the code. That fix it